# How does YAML represent XML attributes?

Tags: xml, yaml

How can I convert this XML to YAML and back again without losing information?

```
<foo bar='one' baz='two'>Lorem Ipsum</foo>
```

My best guess is something like this, but it looks too verbose to me:

```
foo:
  attr: 
    - bar: one
    - baz: two
  value: Lorem Ipsum
```

Second question: Is there syntax similar to this for attributes in YAML?

```
foo ( bar: one, baz: two ): Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: I'm curious what you are trying to do that the YAML representation matters?

Comment: Boost.PropertyTree maps the XML attributes into a key called "xmlattr" https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.xml_parser

Answer (score 3):

If you can assume you can't have duplicate attribute names, your guess can be simplified to use a map:

```
foo:
  attr: 
    bar: one
    baz: two
  value: Lorem Ipsum
```

If you wanted a barely more compact form, you could use YAML flow style, which is similar to JSON and the closest thing to your second question that is available:

```
foo: {attr: {bar: one, baz: two}, value: lorum ipsum}
```

... it isn't very common though.

Answer (score 2):

Various conventions exist to convert from XML to JSON and back, and these conventions translate directly to YAML as well.

You can find a list here: http://wiki.open311.org/JSON_and_XML_Conversion/

There is a python library named **[xmljson](https://github.com/sanand0/xmljson)** that implements most of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer any of the below as per your requirement:

https://github.com/sarnold/ymltoxml
: for yml to xml and vice-versa (attributes within tag)

https://github.com/tarsil/yaml_to_xml : for yml to xml only

**Prerequisite:**
You just need to setup python environment as given in the links.