Is there a standard convention for converting YAML to XML and vice-versa?
I am interested to understand if there is a standard convention (e.g. W3C standard) for converting XML data to YAML and vice-versa. I immagine that there are structures in XML that can be hardly defined in YAML however I saw online many XML to YAML conversion tools and I was wondering if there is a reference standard that they are following or they are just defining their own.

related https://stackoverflow.com/a/43881457/2176756

Both XML and YAML are structural data representation formats. They need external schemas to give semantic to the data. Sometimes those schemas are explicit (for example, XSD schemas for XML, or things like OpenAPI for YAML), sometimes they are implicitly defined by what the tool that processes them expects.
Since there is generally no intrinsic semantic within either format (mind that even if you define the schema of your XML input via xmlns or such, that schema is still external), there cannot be a semantic mapping from one onto the other.
A structural mapping can sometimes be possible even without semantics, such as from JSON to YAML since YAML is a superset of JSON. However in our case, both XML and YAML have features that the other format doesn't support, and are in fact quite different in the structure they represent (for example, in XML a sequence is a concatenation of text content and elements, while in YAML it is a list of arbitrary nodes).
Any general conversion tool will either need to restrict its input and presuppose some semantics to be able to do the conversion, or it actually does not convert but rather describes the content of the input in the syntax of the target format. Both approaches may have some fringe use-cases but are certainly too restrictive to be made into a general standard.
A tool that implements such a conversion should tell you about its restrictions and uses. It might have been implemented for some specific use-case. There is no standard conversion for the reasons discussed.

thanks, but are there any convention for doing that?

There isn't really a use-case for it that would merit such a convention, so none exists. There might be some specific formats that can use both YAML and XML, those would then define some mapping, but such a mapping is not applicable outside that domain. For example, the Java serialization library Jackson supports both XML and YAML, so theoretically it would define a mapping between the two for whatever data structure it serializes, if the caller allows both formats. I have never seen it used that way though.

thanks, that's the information I need because if somebody already create a convention I could reuse that one instead of creating a new one
